# What is the lowest granularity for Prometheus Go client library's ExponentialBuckets API?

Tags: go, prometheus

I am experimenting with [Prometheus Go client library](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#ExponentialBuckets). Does [ExponentialBuckets API](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#ExponentialBuckets) accept parameter `start` of less than 1.0 (e.g., 0.001)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [package prometheus](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus)
>
> ```
> import "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
> ```
>
> [func ExponentialBuckets](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#ExponentialBuckets)
>
> ```
> func ExponentialBuckets(start, factor float64, count int) []float64
> ```
>
> ExponentialBuckets creates 'count' buckets, where the lowest bucket
>   has an upper bound of 'start' and each following bucket's upper bound
>   is 'factor' times the previous bucket's upper bound. The final +Inf
>   bucket is not counted and not included in the returned slice. The
>   returned slice is meant to be used for the Buckets field of
>   HistogramOpts.
>
> The function panics if 'count' is 0 or negative, if 'start' is 0 or
>   negative, or if 'factor' is less than or equal 1.

---

Try `start` equal to the minimum normal positive `float64`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    // Minimum normal positive float64
    // 0 00000000001 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    // 2.2250738585072014e−308
    start := math.Float64frombits(uint64(1 << (63 - 11)))
    fmt.Println(start)
}
```

Output:

```
2.2250738585072014e-308
```